# PowerPivot CALCULATE SUM

Tags: filter, dax, powerpivot

would appreciate any help with this, In PowerPivot I'm trying to do a CALCULATE SUM similar to this in Excel...  Thanks in advance for any help. Gav

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a measure/calculated field you can use:

```
Total_as_measure:=CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Value]))
```

For a calculated column you can use:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Value] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Company], Table1[Date], Table1[Flag] )
)
```

[image]
A general measure (such as above) is evaluated/calculated based on how you use it, i.e, which fields you choose in the PivotTable Rows/slicer, etc and we write specific measures based on specific requirements.

Thanks